Numerical values of physical quantities for using in the table of research paper
I am using method of lines for numerical solution of PDEs in mathematica. I have want to find the different numerical values for physical quantities I.e. skin friction coefficient, Nusselt number, and sheerweood number for which I am using the mathematica sheet code as given in the picture. But here is some issue occurring in my tried, as it can be seen in the picture. So Please help me how to set the mathematica sheet code for system of pdes to find the numerical values of physical quantities.which I am using in the table of my research paper.

Please improve your post. You have to show your code not its picture.

Ok dear I will do that.

The first error says, that there is a bracket nesting error. Right click 'Copy  As  LaTeX'  the NDSolve celland paste it  to a text cell and look for strange characters.
